# iOS-ipad white screen after keyboard show in ionic-AngularJs

Tags: ios, angularjs, ipad, ionic-framework

On iOS, when I tap on some html input:

The keyboard is shown - OK

[image]

I can enter some text and select another inputs (but without closing the keyboard dialog) - OK

[image]

Once the keyboard is closed (either with Done button or just by tapping to non-input space) - the inputs with their labels become white, but I can still type into inputs with white font - so it looks like white screen which overlays the content.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I found two key answer for it**

***First make ion-content to scroll false.***

```
 <ion-content has-bouncing="true" scroll="false" >
```

If this not working then try with second one

***Replacing ion-content with ion-scroll***

```
  Replace <ion-content> with <ion-scroll>

  <ion-scroll direction="y">
```